# passing variable containing space to command in bash

Tags: bash

I have a program that receives some options, like below:

```
root@machine:~$ cat notmodifiable
#!/bin/bash

echo 1: $1
echo 2: $2
echo 3: $3
echo 4: $4
```

And I have a script to pass a variable as argument list to this program, below script demonstrates the logic:

```
root@machine:~$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash

args='a b "c 3" d'
./notmodifiable ${args}
```

When executing this script I got:

```
root@machine:~$ ./myscript
1: a
2: b
3: "c
4: 3"
```

What I want is:

```
1: a
2: b
3: c 3
4: d
```

I can not modify the notmodifiable script(it is actually a ELF binary), how can I achieve this by modify "myscript"?

Comment: Don't do that, variables in `bash` are for scalar values. For multiple values, use an array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)

Answer (score 1):

Use [arrays](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

args=(a b "c 3" d)
./notmodifiable "${args[@]}"
```

Quoting with `[@]` are they keys to passing arguments.

If you omit the quotes, e.g. `./notmodifiable ${args[@]}` you will have the same issues.

If you use `[*]` instead of `[@]`, e.g. `./notmodifiable "${args[*]}"` you will sent a single argument concatenating the entire array.

Comment: Thanks, How to convert a string like 'a b "c 3" d' to the array of (a b "c 3" d) ?

Comment: If you have a fixed string at this point, you will need to choose whether you want an array ith 4 ìtems `a`, `b`, `"c 3"` and `d` or an array with 5 items `a`, `b`, `"c`, `3"` and `d`. I assume you want the former, I would just like to point out that if you reach this confusion you are kind of stuck, which usually means you should have been able to build an array beforehand.

Comment: So if you want the former, the easy way would be to call `eval args=($args)` but this is a very bad practice because it can evaluate malicious code depending on which arguments are given